# Take mean of two or more DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

Consider we have two dataframes:

```
a = DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2]])
b = DataFrame([[1,1],[10,10]])
```

How do we take the mean of two dataframes so that we get:

```
   0  1 
0  1  1
1  6  6
```

Also how can we get standard deviation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the two DataFrames together to get a new one:

```
(a+b)/2
```

Output:

```
     0   1
0    1   1
1    6   6

[2 rows × 2 columns]
```

Or if you wanted to do some more complicate processing on the result:

```
c = a+b
c.std()
```

output:

```
0    7.071068
1    7.071068
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to do more complex tasks like take standard deviation

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add them up, then divide by 2:

```
(a + b) / 2
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  1  1
1  6  6

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Then why did you ask for the mean?